# seo meta description issue in google search

Tags: php, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

This is my first time to use Yoast SEO plugin in my website, I'm trying to add meta description to every pages and every post in my website.

When I search it on google, seems like the meta description does not show at all, instead google take the content from the website page as the meta description.

When I looked at the page source, there is a content that I set in Yoast SEO as my meta description

For keywords part that I put in my SEO, when I test it in SERPs, the keywords seems does not work at all, SERPs couldn't match the keywords that I enter with the keywords that already set in my SEO.

this is my website

> [sunlitex.co.id/en/](http://sunlitex.co.id)

I already change title tag in my page to be like this to match with the SEO

```
<title><?php if ( is_category() ) {
    echo 'Category Archive for &quot;'; single_cat_title(); echo '&quot; | '; bloginfo( 'name' );
} elseif ( is_tag() ) {
    echo 'Tag Archive for &quot;'; single_tag_title(); echo '&quot; | '; bloginfo( 'name' );
} elseif ( is_archive() ) {
    wp_title(''); echo ' Archive | '; bloginfo( 'name' );
} elseif ( is_search() ) {
    echo 'Search for &quot;'.wp_specialchars($s).'&quot; | '; bloginfo( 'name' );
} elseif ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
    bloginfo( 'name' ); echo ' | '; bloginfo( 'description' );
}  elseif ( is_404() ) {
    echo 'Error 404 Not Found | '; bloginfo( 'name' );
} elseif ( is_single() ) {
    wp_title('');
} else {
    echo wp_title( ' | ', false, right ); bloginfo( 'name' );
} ?>
</title>
```

Is there any reference that can explain/help me to make the meta description work and the keywords?

Is there any settings that I need to change from the plugin section?

I also have a question for meta description template from the plugin page, do I just leave it blank or should I add some variables?

Comment: [Cross-posted](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35518076/1591669).

Comment: The easies way to get meta title right is using a SEO plugin like Slim SEO https://wpslimseo.com

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to check what is happening is to check the source code of your pages where the meta description is added through Yoast

```
<meta name="description"
<meta property="og:description" content="
```

Check what the above values say and if there is any conflict. 
If the text in the above meta fields are not as entered through Yoast then it may be a theme issue

Also after you add the meta description it takes a while to show up. It will appear after google indexes your site again.

Comment: The value from both of them showing exactly what I entered through Yoast. But it was not showing in google.